# google scripts: hide sheet by exact name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets file that contains 1 tab per day and the name of each tab is adate in d MMMM yyyy format. Now I have created a script that runs through the file and hides any tabs of which the name is older than today-14, which works beautifully BUT: for some reason it does not look for an exact match but a *contains* match. so for example if it looks for 1 december, it will hide also 11 december as that contains 1 december as well.

Question; How would you suggest I adjust the script to search and hide only an *exact* match?

```
// Get list of sheet names in an array format
function sheetnames() {
// Define array
var out = new Array()
// Get sheets
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
// get current month
  var testDate = new Date();
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(testDate.getDate()-14);
  var secondDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d MMMM").toLowerCase();
  Logger.log(secondDate);
// Work through each sheet one at a time
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
// define the current sheet
    var curSheetName = sheets[i].getName();
// determine if matches criteria
if (curSheetName.indexOf(secondDate) !== -1) {
 sheets[i].hideSheet();
}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The method [String.prototype.indexOf(searchValue)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) cheks either the searchValue is a substring of the specified string

- In other words, it checks either a string contains a susbtring
- This behavior is different from [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- In your case, if you are looking for exact match modify

```
if (curSheetName.indexOf(secondDate) !== -1)
```

to

```
if (curSheetName == secondDate)
```

Comment: that works beautifully. just had to make a minor adjustment to add the year to the secondDate variable, in order to exactly match the tab name now.

var secondDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d MMMM yyyy").toLowerCase();